# Ubuntu virtual desktop like Windows

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, ubuntu-dock, virtualdesktop

I want to change to new virtual desktop,

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> to change desktop

I don't want to see previous virtual desktop application that I am using.

In Windows every Virtual desktop is individual,when I open a game in desktop1, I would not see the game opened in taskbar

OS : Ubuntu 18.04 (I'm not using VM)

First and second virtual desktops:
[image: First virtual desktop] [image: Second virtual desktop]

The brand new virtual desktop I want:
[image: The brand new virtual desktop I want]